# Specify the timeshift parameter in Matlab's cwt()? (continuous 1-D wavelet transform)

Tags: signal-processing, matlab, wavelet

I want to compute the wavelet of a signal with a given scale and timeshift.

In Matlab using the [`cwt()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/cwt.html) function (Continuous 1-D wavelet transform) provided in the [Wavelet Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/index.html) I can specify the scale(s) I want as a parameter to cwt(), and it will return all possible timeshifts:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4];
scales = [3];
wavelet_name = 'db1';
coefs = cwt(x,scales, wavelet_name);

>> coefs =   

   -1.1553   -1.1553   -1.1553    1.7371
```

How can I specify the timeshift (instead of having cwt() computing all possible timeshifts)? I'm aiming at reducing the computation time as I have a bunch of signals to analyze.

To put it visually:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> `[coefs,frequencies] = cwt(x,scales,wname, samplingperiod)`  returns the
>   frequencies in cycles per unit time corresponding to the scales and
>   the analyzing wavelet wname. samplingperiod is a positive real-valued
>   scalar. If the units of `samplingperiod` are seconds, the frequencies
>   are in hertz.

This is taken directly from the Matlab `cwt` page. I think this might be what you're looking for.